# web.xml configuration/structure for Jersey with Bootstrap/REST

Tags: java, html, rest, jersey, glassfish

I use the following technologies: Glassfish, Jersey
I got the following project structure in IntelliJ:

```
beat_api
  ->.idea
  ->lib
  ->out
  ->src
     ->ApplicationController.java
     ->Beat.java
  ->web
     ->WEB-INF
       web.xml
     ->index.jsp (want to convert that to HTML though, no idea how .jsp works)
```

I've got following questions:

1. Is my structure correct? Where do I put .html/.css files to connect
   to my REST api? Once the basic markup is done I want to add Bootstrap to make it look nice.
2. How do I configure the web.xml for my project structure? I don't get it, whatever I tried, I won't be able to display index.jsp from my project structure by going to localhost:8080/beat_api/
3. I want to be able to create "Beat"s and search for
   "Beat"s, preferably in a JSON or XML file (using SAX parser). How can I create a Beat instance in my Beat.java resource? Whenever I put an constructor in there I get the following error message: "java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Could not find a suitable constructor in Beat class."

Beat.java

```
import javax.ws.rs.*;
// The Java class will be hosted at the URI path "/beats"

@Path("/beats")
public class Beat {

    // The Java method will process HTTP GET requests
    // The Java method will produce content identified by the MIME Media type "text/plain"
    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    @Path("/show")
    public String retrieveBeat() {
        return "hello";
    }

    // The Java method will process HTTP GET requests
    // The Java method will produce content identified by the MIME Media type "text/plain"
    @POST
    @Consumes("text/plain")
    @Path("create/{beatname}/{beatbpm}/{beatkey}")
    public void createBeat(@PathParam("beatname") String beatname,
                           @PathParam("beatbpm") int beatbpm,
                           @PathParam("beatkey") String beatkey) {
    }
}
```

ApplicationController.java

```
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

//Defines the base URI for all resource URIs.
@ApplicationPath("/")
//The java class declares root resource and provider classes
public class ApplicationController extends Application{
    //The method returns a non-empty collection with classes, 
    // that must be included in the published JAX-RS application
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        HashSet h = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        h.add( Beat.class );
        return h;
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
</web-app>
```